need some explanation about MySQL where ... in ... subquery

Above is a given table of data and I need to get the result data like the one below.


SELECT ID
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, PARENT_ID
    FROM ECOLI_DATA
    WHERE PARENT_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM ECOLI_DATA WHERE PARENT_ID 
                        IN (SELECT ID FROM ECOLI_DATA WHERE PARENT_ID IS NULL))
) AS aa
ORDER BY 1;

I asked others to get the answer like the code above but I could not figure out the process of this code (subquery part). I figured out what was going on with the first subquery but from the second one, I was lost.
Can someone please explain the detailed process?

Work from the inside out with subqueries.
So the first one is
SELECT ID FROM ECOLI_DATA WHERE PARENT_ID IS NULL

This returns 2 ID's (1 and 2)
Now this will be run with the values 1 and 2 passed to the IN
SELECT ID FROM ECOLI_DATA WHERE PARENT_ID IN(1,2)

So this returns 3 ID's (3,4 and 5)
Now this query is run
SELECT ID, PARENT_ID FROM ECOLI_DATA WHERE PARENT_ID IN(3,4,5)

So this returns
ID      PARENT_ID
6       4
7       3

Now the outermost query is run on the previous resultset
SELECT ID 

Resulting in
ID
6
7

In reality it would appear you could cut one query out of this nest and get the same result
SELECT ID FROM ECOLI_DATA
    WHERE PARENT_ID IN 
        (SELECT ID FROM ECOLI_DATA WHERE PARENT_ID IN 
            (SELECT ID FROM ECOLI_DATA WHERE PARENT_ID IS NULL))
) AS aa
ORDER BY 1;

